# Angular Material - error: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use `<mat-form-field>` in my feature module (UserProfilesModule), but I have got this error:

`ERROR in src/app/user-profiles/components/users/users.component.html:3:5 - error NG8001: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element: 1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.`

Here is my **shared.module.ts**

```
const modules = [
  CommonModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormsModule,
  RouterModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatInputModule,
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [UserInfoComponent],
  imports: modules,
  exports: modules
})// @ts-ignore
export class SharedModule { }
```

Here is my **users.component.html**

```
<div>
  <form>
    <mat-form-field appearance="standart">
      <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Username">
      <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</div>
```

and **user-profiles.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [UsersComponent],
  imports: [
    SharedModule
  ]
})
// @ts-ignore
export class UserProfilesModule { }
```

Comment: did you try restarting your server?  sometimes after installing Material it goes crazy and doesn't work

Comment: I have restarted it several times. After a lot of time, this error just disappeared, but I don't know how